# Which file to select when choosing file for Application Loader to upload iOS App to the store?

Tags: xcode, app-store, application-loader

I am uploading an iPhone and iPad app to the store and have completed all the steps until the Application Loader. I opened Application Loader up, logged in to my iTunes Connect account, selected the app to upload and it shows me the data of the app. It looks like this:
[image: Application Loader - App Info with Personal Info Blanked Out]

I click on choose and ...
[image]

I do not know which file to select and have spent a lot of time surfing the web.
Can someone please help me with this?

Any help is appreciated a ton ;)

Thanks,
Dhruv

Comment: You should select the IPA you previously created and signed with your app store identity.

Comment: No problem. I posted this as an answer you can accept if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the IPA you previously created and signed with your app store identity.